# «Восстановить» значения между известными точками

Tags: python, интерполяция

Имеется график из x и y:

`x = (0, 1, 10, 31, 123, 165, 174, 197, 235, 250, 258, 281, 330, 336)`

`y = (1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно получить значения промежуточных точек для любого `x` с шагом 1. Например в точке X=5 - Y=1.6 или при X=335 y=1.83

`list = [1, 2, 1.9, 1.8, 1.7, 1.6, 1.5, 1,4. 1.3, 1.2, 1.1, 1, ...]`

Как получить такой список `list`?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126388/discussion-on-question-by-------).

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np

lst = [y[0]] 
for x1,y1,x2,y2 in zip(x,y,x[1:],y[1:]): 
    lst.extend(np.linspace(y1,y2,x2-x1)[1:])
```

Можно и без numpy, просто нужно тогда ещё один цикл дописать.

Результат у меня немного не такой как у автора вопроса получается, но если посчитать число шагов между точками, то вроде бы у меня правильно выходит.